# Antlr Lexer Grammar rules

Tags: antlr4, lexer

I'm trying to write antlr lexer grammar rule to validate email addresses.

I've got most of it working, however I am unable to validate that the character '.' does not appear consecutively.

For example, my code passes the example `localpart..domainpart@xyz.com` but it should not.

I've tried several regexes, but nothing seems to work well.

Here is what I have so far:

```
fragment LOCALCHARS_first_last : [a-zA-Z0-9-_~!$&'()*+,;=:]; //local part must not include character '.' 
fragment LOCALCHARS : [a-zA-Z0-9-_~!$&'.()*+,;=:]+;
fragment LOCALPART:  LOCALCHARS_first_last LOCALCHARS LOCALCHARS_first_last; //'.' cannot be first or last character
fragment DOMAINPART: [a-zA-Z0-9-.]+;
fragment EMAIL: LOCALPART '@' DOMAINPART;

CHECKEMAIL: (EMAIL) {
   System.out.println("valid email: "+getText());
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

When you define a fragment `fragment EXAMPLE : [a-z.]+` you can match with it strings like: `abc`, `a.b.c` but also a repetitive ones like: `aaa` and `...`.

### Solution

You need to look on the dot `.` as a separator, that separates email's local and/or domain sub-parts.

```antlr
fragment LOCAL_SUBPART : [a-zA-Z0-9-_~!$&\'()*+,;=:]+;
fragment DOMAIN_SUBPART : [a-zA-Z0-9-]+;

EMAIL: LOCAL_SUBPART ('.' LOCAL_SUBPART)* '@' DOMAIN_SUBPART ('.' DOMAIN_SUBPART)*;
```